# Flask - Active Directory Authentication

Tags: flask

I made a small Flask application and I would like users to be able to authenticate with their Windows NT IDs. I am not a part of the IT team, so I have limited insight into this area and my IT team is not experienced with Python.

How easy would it be to configure this? I tried to do some Googling and I saw LDAP modules and Flask-Security. I am hoping for a quick guide or to be pointed into a specific direction.

- There is an existing Active Directory and a lot of our internal websites use NT authentication
- I made a Flask app that I will be porting to our internal network
- I want users to be able to login to the site with their NT ID
- I need to know what information I need (an LDAP server and port?) or what I need to do with IT to get this configured properly without breaking any security protocols

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is quite easy to work with Flask as it is a lightweight and plugin-based Python web framework.

> Things you will need for LDAP Configuration

- LDAP Host
- LDAP Domain
- LDAP Profile Key

> You need to install Flask-LDAP plugin

```
pip install Flask-LDAP
```

and here is a basic example to get you started:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.ldap import LDAP, login_required

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap.example.com'
app.config['LDAP_DOMAIN'] = 'example.com'
app.config['LDAP_SEARCH_BASE'] = 'OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=com'

ldap = LDAP(app)
app.secret_key = "welfhwdlhwdlfhwelfhwlehfwlehfelwehflwefwlehflwefhlwefhlewjfhwelfjhweflhweflhwel"
app.add_url_rule('/login', 'login', ldap.login, methods=['GET', 'POST'])

@app.route('/')
@ldap.login_required
def index():
    pass

# @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# def login():
#     pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

More details can be found [here](http://flask-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: Flask-LDAP version 0.1.6 throws this error: "AttributeError: 'LDAP' object has no attribute 'login_required'".  Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

For `Name: Flask-LDAP, Version: 0.1.6` use this:

To install: 
`pip install Flask-LDAP`

and import by:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ldap import LDAP, login_required
```

then follow along Priyank's example.