# Enable autologin into flask app using active directory

Tags: python, flask, authentication, active-directory

I have made flask web app meant to be used within my organisation.

My problem is currently the login works by requesting a username and password from the user which are then authenticated by an LDAP server.

I would like to be able to **autologin** **a user** immediately he gets onto the site since that's how other company internal websites work(**these others were made in C# and php**)

My main problem is:

- **Is there a python package to get the client's windows username immediately he gets on to the site? and how would I use it**

[Requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/blob/master/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py) was once suggested but it has no documentation.

I have tried to look at several stack overflow questions but they do not address my problem eg [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684463/flask-active-directory-authentication)

Comment: I do not think you can be able to get the requesting user's Windows username through the request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has taken me weeks to find the answer but **Yes** **it is possible** but you must configure the server where your app is hosted to allow this. In my case I was using IIS and enabled windows authentication.
With this its surprisingly easy to get the active directory user name as it comes as part of the HTTP response:

```
from flask import request
username = request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
```

See this question for more information:

[How to access Apache Basic Authentication user in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940651/how-to-access-apache-basic-authentication-user-in-flask)

Comment: To my knowledge ASP.NET Impersonation is not needed in this case, because it is only for ASP.NET applications (and you are using Python). Windows Authentication is the only option which has to be enabled.

Comment: You do not need ASP.net Impersonation. 
Just enable Windows Authentication and you should be all Set!

Comment: Is there a way to get password as well as?